# How to set shipping-methods for multiplte countrys?

Tags: php, html, mysql

in my script a seller can set one national shipping-cost and one international, but thats not enough. If a customer is sitting in a country at the other side of the world, its much more expensive as he is sitting at the neighbour Country.

My Idea was to give the seller the ability to chose 13 Countrys and Regions and set the shipping-cost for it.
The biggest problem is, if the seller choose i.e. 10 of the 13 Regions, the "shipping-country list" is much to long at the article page.
What is the best solution to store multiple Shipping-Costs and Methods in mysql and show only the relevant entrys to the customer?

In mysql i was thinking the following is the best solution:

```
id|article|shipping-desc |price|japan|china|europe|america|england|german|
1 |134    |Pakage        |5,90 |  0  |  0  |  0   |   0   |   0   |   1 
2 |134    |Insured-Pakage|23,90|  0  |  0  |  1   |   1   |   1   |   0 
3 |134    |Insured-Pakage|43,90|  1  |  1  |  0   |   0   |   0   |   0
```

Then take the datas from mysql to the article-page to show them to the customer:

```
SHIPPINGCOST(NATIONAL)        5,90€  -  Pakage
SHIPPINGCOST(INTERNATIONAL)   23,90€ -  Insured-Pakage (europe,america,england,one more,...)
SHIPPINGCOST(INTERNATIONAL)   43,90€ -  Insured-Pakage (japan,china)
```

And there it is much to long if there are more than two or three countrys.
Has anyone a really good solution that dont messed up my article page?

Best greetings from Germany!

Comment: you should normalize your schema  ..

Comment: The Table structure from scaisEdge is great and i will create it this way. What is now the best solution to keep the article page clean from to many shipping-methods at one price?

Answer (score 1):

You should use normalized  table eg:

```
table articles 
id, article_code, shipping_desc_id, country_area_code, price
1, 134, 1, GER, 5,90
2, 134, 2, RPC, 23,90  
3, 134, 2, AME, 23,90  



table country_area
country_area_code, country_area_name
JPN, japan
PRC, china
AME, america
GER, German


shipping_method 
shipping_desc_id, shipping_desc_name
1, Package
2, Insured-Pakage
```

Comment: I wrote another comment in my Post on Top: What is the best solution to keep the article page clean from to many shipping-methods at one price?

Comment: @tobiass   . change or extend the question is not fair and is not the best way for obtain a proper answer .. you should post a new specific question .. so all the community can help ..you